# Is the length limit of AES-GCM per key or per (key, nonce) pair?

Tags: aes, gcm

AES-GCM has a limit on the length of the plaintext it encrypts: $2^{39} - 256$ bits. But is this limit per key or per (key, nonce)? That is, if I encrypt a message with the maximum length, and encrypt another message with the same key but different nonce, will it be secure still?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is per message. I.e. per (key, nonce) -pair.

The reason it exists is that GCM uses CTR mode for encryption with (normally) a 32-bit counter. That means you can only encrypt $2^{32}$ blocks, i.e. $2^{39}$ bits with AES. The 256 bits that are subtracted are due to authentication.

So you can encrypt multiple maximum-length messages securely.

Comment: actually per spec there is a soft block limit of $2^{64}$ and a hard nonce limit of $2^{32}$ (if not using 96-bit IVs), whichever comes first

Comment: @RichieFrame, good to know, but I guess that doesn't really change the answer?

Comment: @RichieFrame: What does the soft block limit mean?

Comment: @SiyuanRen the soft block limit is a recommended maximum authenticated block count with a single key, soft because it is not a strict limit. Encrypting too many blocks or generating too many authentication tags can allow recovery of the hash subkey, and thus forging of new tags.

Comment: @RichieFrame: What are those limit if the nounce if 96-bit?

Comment: @SiyuanRen Nonce limit is more complex, and takes into account the max message size, as well as the tag size. To keep security above $2^{64}$ do not exceed $2^{28.9}$ 96-bit nonces if you are encrypting very large data sets (GB+), and use 128-bit tags if you are processing more than 1MB of data per nonce. For other size nonces, I would not exceed $2^{9.2}$ for large data sets, that is how bad the security drops. I would also limit the blocks to $2^{48}$ per key for 96-bit nonces and $2^{40}$ for others